# Comparing variable image to static image

Tags: algorithms, computer-vision, image-processing

What are Levenshtein distance algorithms, but for images?

I will have one static image (the target: what it should look like) and one variable image (actual: what the user has created)

For example,

Target:

[image: "K" sample]

The following should be classified as "close enough"

Actual:

[image: "K" from user]

But the following should be classified as "incorrect" (even though it has 2 strokes and fills the '|' part)

[image: "b" from user]

I will be using this as a guide for users new to the English alphabet to practice on writing.

I will, of course, have other checks in place such as counting the number of strokes made (2 for 'K', 1 for '|', 1 for '<') and also checking to see if the area covered is reasonable (filling whole area should not be identified as "correct").

The user "drawing" will only be in black and white (not greyscale).

I suppose I could train a neural network (like handwriting recognition) but only to identify if it is "close enough". I think this is overkill as this only requires checking to see if it matches a single image and not selecting the best-matching image from a set.

Comment: The Levenshtein algorithm is an efficient way to compute the Levenshtein distance. I'm not sure which came first. Do you have any particular metric in mind, or are you looking for any reasonable metric which is efficiently computable?

Comment: Judging from your example, a reasonable metric which is easy to compute would be the number of differing pixels, though in practice you will probably have to handle geometric issues such as shifting, rotation and scaling.

Comment: I suggest looking up *image alignment*, a similar problem of interest in computer vision.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I am looking for any reasonable metric. It doesn't need to be too efficient - this is only for learning purposes. If it is efficient, it would be a bonus.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: the Levenshtein distance is irrelevant here.

Comment: Your question is insufficiently specified. You should say if the characters have the same size, if they are correctly aligned and if an identical character but in another font should be accepted or not. I believe that you example is too simplistic.

Comment: "I will have other checks in place such as counting the number of strokes made": such a feature is very difficult to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're really asking for a distance metric on images.  Based on  your examples, I would suggest the L2 distance (sum of squares of differences in pixel intensities) or L1 distance; possibly after aligning the images.  This looks like it should b effective for the examples you list.

Comment: As the images are binary, L1 and L2 distances make no difference.